# How do I trigger an event on image position change using jquery animations?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I am using jquery to move an image from one side of the screen to another, when the image reaches a certain position during its animation (around halfway through) I want to call another animation. How do I get the coordinates during the animation? I'm creating a simple images slideshow that will move images from one side to another. I will place them all off screen and when the first image is past the starting point I want to start to animate the second and so on. I'm not looking for a quick solution so much as I am asking how to set event handlers for objects being manipulated by jquery via animation. Either is welcome.

```
$( ".slideshowImages" ).click(function() {
     $( ".slideshowImages" ).animate({
     "margin-left": "-=1300",
     }, 10000, function() {
              // Animation complete.
     });
});
```

Edit

The images all have varying width.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery I guess you cant set coordnate when is in half way, only set in half time animation to start new one

first animation lasts 3 sec 
second start in 1,5

In css use animation with transition and you can achive that

Comment: I could do that if the images all had the same width but the width varies with each image.I would like to keep the distance between the images equal so this wouldn't really work for me.

Comment: yeah I get it , so I vote up for this question cuz I was looking for same some time ago. Peace

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear to me what you are trying to achieve but there is no event handler for  "objects being manipulated by jquery via animation". There is only a way to check if the element is being animated:

```
if($(elemement).is(':animated')) {/*do something*/}
```

What is that coordinates you are referring to, is that the left and top `offset()` positon of the image? In jQuery `animate()` there is a [**step**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step) function, a callback function that is fired at each step of the animation. That may help you check and make a condition if the current position of the image is greater than or less than, but don't use equal to `'=='` there is no guarantee that on a certain step will return a value equal to what you are comparing.

Test it on [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vnsLg/).

---

I made a simple slider that may be similar to what you are trying to do and may help you get things started.

html markup:

```
<div id="sliderWindow">
    <img class="slideshowImages" src="" />
    <img class="slideshowImages" src="" />
    <img class="slideshowImages" src="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sliderWindow {
background:#333;
position:relative;
width:300px;
height:100px;
margin-left:100px;
overflow:hidden;
}

.slideshowImages {
position:absolute;
left:100%;
opacity:1;
}
```

jQuery:

```
//function that calculates the left value to center the img
function center(el) {
    return ($('#sliderWindow').width() / 2) - (el.width() / 2)
}

//center the first img
var $first = $('.slideshowImages:first');
$first.css({'left': center($first)});
//set the duration of animate
var duration = 1000;

$('.slideshowImages').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        //distance traverse from current position until completely hidden
        distance = $this.width() + center($this),
        //get the speed 
        speed = distance / duration,
        /*calculate the duration if it's only to travel 
          half it's left margin at the same rate
        */
        halfway = (center($this) / 2) / speed;

    $this.animate({
        'left': -Math.abs($this.width()) //hide on the left
    }, duration);

    //halfway, trigger animate on the next img
    setTimeout(function () {
        $this.next().animate({
            left: center($this.next())
        }, duration);
    }, halfway);
});
```

Here is the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/4gJ4q/1/).